# object not working in javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function Calculation() {
    this.priceBase = Number('@Json.Encode(Model.Price)');
    this.dataSize = Number($('#ddlSize').find(':selected').data('size-id'));
    this.dataColor = Number($('#dvSelected').data('color-id'));
}

Calculation.prototype.getDisplayPrice = function () {
    var selectedId = $('option[data-size-id=' + this.dataSize + '][data-color-id=' + this.dataColor + ']');
    return selectedId.data('price');
};

Calculation.prototype.getSelectedId = function () {
    var selectedId = $('option[data-size-id=' + this.dataSize + '][data-color-id=' + this.dataColor + ']');
    return selectedId;
};

$('#ddlSize').change(function () {
    var objCalculation = new Calculation();

    $('.color-block').hide();

    objCalculation = new Calculation();

    $('#lblPrice').html(objCalculation.getDisplayPrice());        

    $('#txtQuantity').attr('placeholder', 'Quantity (Max: ' +
        objCalculation.getSelectedId().attr('data-quantity') + ')');
});
```

On change function when I remove **`objCalculation = new Calculation();`** I dont get the object whereas with `objCalculation = new Calculation()` there get the required object and hence required result

**Am I missing something??**

```
var objCalculation = new Calculation();

$('.color-block').hide();

$('#lblPrice').html(objCalculation.getDisplayPrice());

$('#txtQuantity').attr('placeholder', 'Quantity (Max: ' +
    objCalculation.getSelectedId().attr('data-quantity') + ')');
```

Comment: A lot of this code seems unnecessary

Comment: @IanBrindley can you be specific??

Comment: Have you wrapped your *change* event registration code in a DOM ready event? It is not shown and would cause problems.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie obviously yes:-)

Comment: I tried to put your code in fiddle, and I guess i don't know what you're trying to accomplish cause it seems to work. I just had to change a few things:  http://jsfiddle.net/SggCY/4/

Comment: @brykneval: If it was obvious it would not be one of the most common cause of jQuery problems :) Please update josephnvu's JSFiddle to suit and/or add more details to question. Thanks.